# Mask variable passed to sql query in ksh script

Tags: sql, bash, variables, ksh

Hi I'm writing a ksh script to change DBA password in whole environment. I'm prompting user to provide new password and set it as $newPwd variable. The problem is when I pass this variable to sql query it shows the password in the log file.

```
sqlplus sys/sysPwd@db<<EOf>dba_password_change_log.log
Alter user $dba_user identified by $newPwd;
quit;
EOF
```

$ cat dba_password_change_log.log

Alter user SCOTT identified by T1ger;

How can I mask the $newPwd variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way. I just used the plsql procedure instead.

```
declare
          emesg varchar2(32000);
        begin
          dbms_output.put_line('alter user ${dba_user} identified by *******');
          execute immediate 'alter user ${dba_user} identified by "${newPwd}"';
          exception when others then
            emesg := SQLERRM;
            raise_application_error(-20001, 'alter user ${dba_user} command failed: '|| emesg);
        end;
        /
```

Now when I open the log file it will only show the below error message or other error messages.

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: alter user  command failed: ORA-28007: the password cannot be reused
ORA-06512: at line 8

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt it to your log file. You will need to use some code to pass it to pgp or some other encryption program.